# Access MyPanel class buttons from MyListener class

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 classes: `BabboNatale` (the main class), `MyPanel` which extends `JPanel`, and `MyListener` which implements `ActionListener` and which I would use to manage `MyPanel` buttons.

Here comes my problem: how can I access `MyPanel` buttons from `MyListener` without putting the class inside `MyPanel`?

Here is what I wrote so far:

*BabboNatale.java*

```
package graphic;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import presents.Abbigliamento;
import presents.Elettronica;
import presents.Gioco;
import presents.Regalo;

public class BabboNatale {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
    int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
    MyFrame f = new MyFrame("Babbo Natale", width/4, height/4, width/2, height/2);
    Container c = f.getContentPane();
    JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    c.add(panel);

    f.show();
    }

}
```

*MyPanel.java*

```
package graphic;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import presents.Abbigliamento;
import presents.Elettronica;
import presents.Gioco;
import presents.Regalo;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

    public MyPanel(){
        super();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Aggiungi regalo");
        b1.addActionListener(new MyListener());
        add(b1);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Ricerca regalo");
        b2.addActionListener(new MyListener());
        add(b2);
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Elimina regalo");
        b3.addActionListener(new MyListener());
        add(b3);
        JButton b4 = new JButton("Azzera campi");
        b4.addActionListener(new MyListener());
        add(b4);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        String str;

    //  g.setColor(Color.white);
    //  g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12);
        Font titolo = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 38);
        g.setFont(titolo);
        str = "BABBO NATALE";
        //calculate str display length
        int center = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(str)/2;
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString(str, this.getWidth()/2 - center, 50);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        str = "Babbo Natale 23/12/2016";
        int pad = 5;
        g.drawString(str, pad, this.getHeight() - pad);
   }
}
```

*MyListener.java*

```
package graphic;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import presents.Abbigliamento;
import presents.Elettronica;
import presents.Gioco;
import presents.Regalo;

public class MyListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object pressedButton = e.getSource();
        if(pressedButton == b1){    //error

        }
        if(pressedButton == b2){    //error

        }
        if(pressedButton == b3){    //error

        }
        if(pressedButton == b4){    //error

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply use `ActionCommand`.
While creating `JButton` set the action command like:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Aggiungi regalo");
b1.setActionCommand("b1"); //so on for the rest of the buttons, b2, b3..
```

Next fetch the action command from the `ActionEvent`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String pressedButton = e.getActionCommand();
    if(pressedButton.equals("b1")){
     ////
    }
```

With switch-case, in-case JDK 7 or above:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    switch(e.getActionCommand()){
       case "b1":
                //
           break;
       //...
    }
```

Comment: that's not exactly what I was looking for but it fixed my problem, thanks.